# Execute .bat file from Java, why Eclips project-directory matters?

Tags: java, batch-file, runtime.exec

I want to execute a `.bat` file from a Java program.

I declared the command for the `.bat` like:

`"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "C:\\File\\batfile.bat"`

I use Windows XP and Eclipse Helios.

#### Code

```
String cmd;
        try {
            String[] command = { "cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "C:\\File\\batfile.bat" };
                Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process p = r.exec(command);
                p.waitFor();

                } catch (Exception e) 
                {

                System.out.println("Execution error");}
```

Why is it looking for my `.bat` file in the **project directory** of Eclipse?

Comment: It works perfectly for me, using the same example you have provided. Not sure what is not working.

Comment: try running the same class from console

Comment: Just double check if you have not named your bat file as `batfile.bat.txt`. You can do so by going to `My Computer > Tools > Folder Options > Uncheck 'Hide extensions of known file types'`

Comment: Thank you, i try to uncheck 'hide extensions of knoww file types' but there is change. I almost finished my small project but i can't can't distribute it now because of this problem. I tried to convert .bat file .exe file but i have the same result.Could be a problem with the version of java? dos? windows xp?

Comment: Do you really need the `start` here? If I remember right, this is `start.exe` which could be also called directly.

Answer (score 1):

The process cmd.exe (picked from your PATH environment variable) is created with the current working directory the same as in the parent process (eclipse.exe = java). That is most likely c:\eclipse or the workspace dir.

If it cant find the file (C:\File\batfile.bat) it tries the current working dir. If you run this code using Run As Java try to change the working directory there. Also make sure the BAT file does exist.

Comment: Yes, if i change the directory, i mean if copy the .bat file in c:\Eclipse\workspace\myproject , then it works well. But if i compile my project and create a runnable jar and launch this code in another computer will it work? and why it is working for others person here? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
String com = System.getEnv("ComSpec") != null ? System.getEnv("ComSpec") : "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";

String[] command = { com, ...... }
```

ComSpec is often set to the path of cmd.exe. If not, use the full (expected path). You could also look for it in %SystemRoot%\system32. Or even %path%. But just checking ComSpec is better than using cmd.exe with nothing else by default.

As someone else pointed out, your default working directory when running from Eclipse is usually the Eclipse project folder.

It's generally good practice not to rely on the working folder being anything useful. Instead specify paths to anything needed, or search the path (if the app doesn't do so for you).

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Start` from the command - it's unnecessary - and try:

```java
String[] command = { "cmd.exe", "/C", "C:\\File\\batfile.bat" };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\File\\batfile.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the execution of a specific file, provide the **complete path** instead of just the executable name (which will only run from context of where the JVM was started - possibly unexpected within some IDE):

```
try{
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec(".bat file complete path");
    } catch(IOException e) {
         System.out.println("exception");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same scenario and following helped me to execute `bat` successfully via java.

```
String[] commands = {"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/c", "bat_script_location.bat"};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands, null, "output_directory_path");
process.waitFor();
int statusBatchJob = process.exitValue(); // to check the status of execution
```