# Running Corba Naming Service Inside The Code

Tags: java, corba

Before I am able to run the CORBA Server, I have to open the command prompt and type

```
start orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050
start tnameserv -ORBInitialPort 1055
```

Is it possible to put those inside the code?

Meaning, instead of opening the command prompt every time I need to run the server, can the code itself have it run for me?

Or is this the only [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090059/execute-bat-file-from-java)?

Thanks again

Comment: if you are using JacORB (better than default Java ORB) you can get the source code and do whatever you want with that. :-)

Comment: too bad, I am using the default Java ORB

Comment: You can still open java source code and try to execute from there.